# How can I pull data from a CSV file and populate an HTML table with it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv

So, I have seen similar questions, but I haven't been able to get a working answer. Everyday a company is going to FTP a file to our server. We already know the file name and where it will go on the server. Our job is to take the data and insert it into an HTML table. Inserting the data is the easy part, it's getting the data that has been the problem. If I can just get the entire CSV file (it only has 4 values) as a string, I would be able to do it using regex.

I tried to make an XMLHTTPRequest with AJAX, and then use responseText to get the data as the string. After having no luck there, I tried to use JQuery to get it. This is my code, but I always get 'An error occurred' logged to the console. I am thinking maybe it just can't process the csv file. Also, file.csv is in the same directory as index.aspx right now, hence the file path you see in the code. We don't want to cache the file since it gets updated daily. Thanks for your help.

NOTE: The code below has been corrected. If you have a similar problem, this code should work for you. Make sure you double check your file path and do not use 'dataType: *type*' in the $.ajax block.

```
 // Wait for the DOM to be ready
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Use JQuery promises to make AJAX XMLHttpRequest
            promise = $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"file.csv",
                cache:false
            });

            // Run script when file is ready
            promise.done(function(data){
                console.log(data);

                // Table IDs represented as an array
                var ids = ['date', 'fund', 'change', 'points'];

                // Update table
                for (var x = 0; x < ids.length; x++) {
                    document.getElementById(ids[x]).innerHTML = data[x];
                }
            });

            // Run script if request fails
            promise.fail(function() {
                console.log('A failure ocurred');
            });

        });
```

Comment: Since your URL is relative (i.e. `"file.csv"`), have you checked it's not just a simple 404 error? The path could just be wrong? In the network tab of developer tools in your browser, check the full details of the request you're making to `file.csv`. Cut out the javascript for now, just navigate directly to that csv and make sure the path is good.

Comment: @JayMee is probably right; the other thing I'd check is if the server running the code can access the file system it's on - if it's a network file system, it may be password protected which could cause issues.

Comment: ...I don't think that jQuery has a CSV parser...

Comment: Thanks, JayMee. I actually think the problem is that I am using ASP.NET or the formatting of my company's server. I ran this on a mac (using XAMPP) and it worked fine. However, in case anyone else has a similar problem, data is one big string. I split it into an array using data.split(','); and then inserted it into the table. Long story short, it works now! The reason it wasn't working is either the ASP.NET (which I heard handles AJAX differently) or it was more than likely the file path.

Comment: `dataType:"text/csv"` is wrong. you need to use  `dataType:"text"`.

Comment: Never mind, it runs fine on ASP.NET. It works for my boss, but not for me, so I assume it is a privileges issue. If anyone else has a similar problem, this code works. Thank you everyone who commented!

Comment: `dataType` should be: `xml`, `script`, `html`, `json`, `jsonp` or `text` or mix of two of that like `text xml` ecc... NO OTHER. take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Comment: Thanks @Frogmouth, It started working after removing dataType: entirely. I am going to edit the code above so that people who see it know it works.

Comment: For your knowledge, function called by`.fail()` method has 3 attributes: `jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});` that can help you to debug the request. WIth `text/csv` like `dataType` the attribute `textStatus` is `parsererror `

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it working by changing the dataType:"text".

Also included the code to parse the csv file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    promise = $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"text",
        url:"file.csv",
        cache:false
    });

    promise.done(function(data){

        //Parse CSV File
        //split on new line
        var dataArr = data.split("\n");

        //for each line in array
        $.each(dataArr,function(){
            if (this != "") {

                //split files and create row
                var row = new String("");
                valArr = this.split(",");
                    row += "<tr>"

                $.each(valArr, function(){
                    row += "<td>" + this +"</td>"
                });     

                    row += "</tr>"

                    //Add row to table
                    $('tbody').append(row);

            }

        });

    });

    // Run script if request fails
    promise.fail(function() {
       console.log('A failure ocurred');
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Fund</th>
            <th>Change</th>
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there something I can do to gent the daily min , max and average?